# Append url part into main url using angularjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a url path as shown below.

```
http://localhost:12534/urlpart1/urlpart2?querystring=140
```

So I need to replace the "urlpart2" with the "urlpart3" by using javascript or anugularjs.How can I do that.I can get the whole url by using:

```
  var urlPath = window.location.href;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `replace('urlpart2', 'urlpart3')`?

Comment: @dfsq Can I have more details ? May be as an answer section ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just need to replace specific string `urlpart2` you can go with simple replace method: `var newUrlPath = urlPath.replace('urlpart2', 'urlpart3')`. Try it and see if it's what you need.

Comment: var urlPath = window.location.href.replace('urlpart2', 'urlpart3')

Comment: @dfsq Yes,It's working.Can you put it as an answer.Then I can accept it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to replace specific substring `urlpart2` you can go with simple [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```
var urlPath = window.location.href;
var newUrlPath = urlPath.replace('urlpart2', 'urlpart3');
```